# Is the numpy documentation for calculating the 2nd order norm of a matrix across the columns slightly misleading?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I was trying to figure out how to calculate the Frobenius of a matrix  in numpy. This way I can get the 2-norm of each row in the matrix x below:
My question is about the `ord` parameter in numpy's `linalg.norm` module and how the [relevant part of numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) describes which norm of a matrix one can calculate. I was able to get the Frobenius norm by setting `ord=2`, however, it says that only setting `ord=None` gives the Frobenius norm.

[image: The Table Provided in numpy documentation]

Here is my example:

```
x = np.array([[0, 3, 4],
          [1, 6, 4]])
```

I found that I can the Frobenius norm with the following line of code:

```
x_norm = np.linalg.norm(x, ord = 2, axis=1,keepdims=True )

>>> x_norm
    array([[ 5.        ],
           [ 7.28010989]])
```

My question is whether the documentation here would be considered not as helpful as possible and if this warrants a request to change the description of setting `ord=2` in the aforementioned table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not taking a matrix norm. Since you've passed `axis=1`, you're taking vector norms, and you should be looking at the vector norm column instead of the matrix norm column.

For vector norms, `ord=None` and `ord=2` both produce a 2-norm.

Comment: Thanks, this clarified things for me and help me improve my understanding. Please let me know if you think my question should not have been asked and I will ask to have it deleted.